# "unter anderem" und "unter anderen"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Erste Frage: Welcher Satz wird bei [diesem Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGSQF4Cc43A&feature=youtu.be&t=3m9s) an der Stelle 3:09 gesagt?

> (1) Nicht die Schüler haben ihn zum besten Lehrer Deutschlands gewählt, sondern eine Jury, die unter andere**m** aus Experten der Bildungsministerien besteht.
>
> (2) Nicht die Schüler haben ihn zum besten Lehrer Deutschlands gewählt, sondern eine Jury, die unter andere**n** aus Experten der Bildungsministerien besteht.

Zweite Frage: Sind theoretisch beide Sätze korrekt?

Comment: Könnte vielleicht noch jemand ein paar passende Tags hinzufügen? Ich weiß nicht, welche für so eine Frage passend wären.

Answer (score 2):

Ich höre (1). Allgemein habe ich bis jetzt eig. immer "unter andere**m**" gehört. Aber trotzdem würde ich sagen, dass auch (2) korrekt ist, denn man kann ja sagen:

> Die Jury besteht aus Experten der Bildungsministerien und Anderen/anderen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich höre "unter andere**n**" und laut unten stehendem Artikel sind beide Varianten korrekt:

[Fragen zur Deutschen Sprache](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2015/09/14/unter-anderem-geht-immer-unter-anderen-nicht/)